# How to estimate effective area of contact between rough surfaces as function of surface roughness

Tags: structural-engineering, design, bolting

The engineering problem that I am trying to solve is the following: I have two elements of a magnetic circuit that I must keep in contact through threaded fasteners. The primary objective is to maximize the contact area between the surfaces in order to minimize the magnetic reluctance of the circuit.

The type of screws that I can use (M3) is fixed due to dimensional constraints. On the other hand, I am more free to vary the number of fasteners in the joint and the applied pretension (by varying the type of steel of the bolts).

Once I have fixed the number of fasteners and the pretension, I run an ansys simulation to get an estimation of the contact pressure distribution between the surfaces of the two elements. The step that I am missing is how to use this pressure to estimate the effective area of contact. Of course, the smoother the surfaces, the higher the effective contact area. Since I still have to fix the surface roughness for the two elements, I would like to find a way to estimate the effective contact area as a function of the contact pressure and surface roughness.

In such a way, I will be able to find the best compromise between number of bolts, applied pretension and prescribed surface roughness for the elements.

P.S. If you know any textbook or reference where a similar problem is examined, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: You should be able to get the contact area corresponding to the simulation directly from Ansys.  However, I wouldn't put much faith in the accuracy  of either the contact pressure or the contact area.  It's only a rough estimate that depends strongly on the discretization.  Once you have the total contact area, you can compute the "effective" area based on **your** definition of roughness.  Johnson's book on Contact Mechanics is still the standard reference for all things related to contact.